# Jquery dialog open delay in Javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a save button in my pure HTML page where i call a JS function which uses XMLHttpRequest to save data. I am trying to implement a JQuery modal popup , which will show a loading image when the save button is clicked. But it takes nearly 2 seconds for dialog to open , can anyone please tell me why.

Here is the HTML part

```
<div id="dialog1" title="Waiting" style="text-align:center;background-color:#ffffff;border:none;display:none;">
   <img src="~/Images/icon-load.gif" border="0" align="left" hspace="12" height="175" width="175" />
```

Here is the JS part

```
function addnewentity() {


var aa= document.getElementById('aaa').value;
var bb= document.getElementById('bbb').value;
var cc= document.getElementById('ccc').value;
var validation = document.getElementById("valmsgentity");

if (aa!= "" && bb!= "" && cc!= "") {

    validation.style.display = "none";
    $('#dialog1').dialog('open');
    $("#dialog1").prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();

    var source = {
        "A": aa, "B":bb , "C": cc
    }

    var jsonsource = JSON.stringify(source);
    var method = "POST";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = function () {
        var status = request.status;
        var data = request.responseText;
    }
    request.open(method, createurl, false);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    request.send(jsonsource);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#dialog1').dialog('close');

        ScrollToTop();

        $("#message").show();

        //200 OK ; 201 Created ; 202 Accepted
        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 201 || request.status == 202) {

            $("#message").text('Added successfully!!!');
            $("#message").css("color", "green");
            setTimeout(function () { fadeLabelOut(); }, 5000);
            setTimeout(function () { location.reload(); }, 7000);
        }
        else {

            $("#message").text("Failed to add !!!");
            $("#message").css("color", "red");
            setTimeout(function () { fadeLabelOut(); }, 5000);
            console.log(request.responseText);
        }
    }, 2500);
}
else {
    validation.style.display = "block";
}
```

}

Comment: Change false to true in request.open(...). You want async, not sync.

Comment: If its synchronous, it means the request will wait for response for the program execution to continue rt? So i am calling the open method first , so the dialog will open , then only we are calling the xmlhttprequest and waiting for response and doing the rest, so why the delay then. Anyway ur suggestion work :)

Comment: But that change, made a serious problem, because my condition where the response code is checked is always showing failed as that line of code is not waiting for the response to come

Comment: It's good practice not to block the JS by using async. In this case, what calls addnewentity()? Something might be delaying that

Comment: We fill out some text box and click a button. The button's onclick is that method. Then the JS gets the textbox values, create the request,which then creates an entity. So what i thought is that, once we click the button, the modal pop up comes and it will stay open till the response is reached. I rewrote the code like this, on the requestreadystate, wrote the rest of the code. Like this 
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {....My code here ....}

Comment: I referred this URL [Ref URL](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp)

Comment: I was playing around with your code, and on my machine it seemed like it took a couple seconds just to run a vanilla `dialog('open');`. I ran some timing tests and the `open()` is executed immediately, but the UI takes time to render. I found a similar thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239841/jquery-ui-dialog-slow) and it seems that the UI dialog is just really heavy.

Comment: i have 3 dialogs in my page and the only difference this dialog has compared to the other two is that this dialog has image as content , the other two has none. I checked the image size and its only 5.4kb .
And as per the link you shared,i went through it before and as you can see from my code above,the draggable and rezise are both false. Actually now after making the JS to async its working now and i wrote the call back codes in the xmlhttpreq object's ready state . So i guess all are fine now . But it still confuses me why that much time lag???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was able to solve the problem by making the request async and writing the dependent code after success/failure in the request.readyStateChanged event like this.

```
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {

            $('#dialog1').dialog('close');
            ScrollToTop();

            $("#message").show();

            //200 OK ; 201 Created ; 202 Accepted
            if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 201 || request.status == 202) {
                $("#message").text('Attribute deleted successfully!!!');
                $("#message").css("color", "green");
                setTimeout(function () { fadeLabelOut(); }, 5000);
                setTimeout(function () { attributedetails(); }, 6500);
            }
            else {
                $("#message").text("Failed to add attribute!!!");
                $("#message").css("color", "red");
                setTimeout(function () { fadeLabelOut(); }, 5000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks Drakes for the asyn input, that really helped me out.